# When I set the direction of xamarin forms flyout page to RTL, a gap appears between the side menu and the mobile screen, how can I remove it?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QxYs8.png)
I want to remove this gap shown in the image below, I want it as if it was on the left side without a gap.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @Community I have flyout page in xamarin forms project, I set flow direction Right To Left, when I show side menu there is a gap between it and screen as in picture above.

Comment: If you set the direction as default(LTR), does the gap still appear?

Comment: @LiyunZhang-MSFT No, it appears in RTL only.

Comment: I have done a sample but I didn't meet this problem. The flayout page showed correctly. Can you show more details?

Answer (score 1):

Updating the **Xamarin.Forms nuget to 5.0.0.2515** in both shared and Android projects has resolved the issue.

I too faced the issue when trying to set flyout page flow direction to RTL in Tab, where it worked fine in mobile device.

I guess the issue has been fixed in the Xamarin.Forms - 5.0.0.2515